# useCallback wrap a simple function in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to understand the utility of `useCallback` in ReactJs. I read that useCallback is used to memoise the function inside it, and to trigger the callback depending by dependecies. How i notice we should use this hook when  pass a function as a prop. In the same time i found an example on the internet and i can't figure out why the hook is used.

```
const useAsync = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)

  const execute = useCallback(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    return asyncFunc()
      .then(res => {
        setData(res)
        return res
      })
  }, [])

}
```

Why `execute` function is wrapped by this hook in this example? And in general should we use useCallback if we don't pass a function as a parameter in a compoenent?

Comment: It depend how to use `execute`

Answer (score 1):

Definition:

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
);
```

> Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

So yes it returns a memoized callback, but is basically used, in general, to factorize some redundant operations (like a call to an API).

In your case, suppose you have a `useCallback` like this:

```
const useAsync = (asyncFunc) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)

  const execute = useCallback(() => {
    return asyncFunc()
      .then(res => {
        setData(res)
        return res
      })
  }, [asyncFunc])

 return { execute, data };
}
```

Now let's use it in a component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const { execute, data } = useAsync(myFunction);

  useEffect(() => {
     execute();
  }, [execute]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(el => ...)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Where `myFunction` is:

```
function myFunction() {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3001/users/')
        .then((response) => { 
            return response.json().then((data) => {
                return data;
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }) 
        });
}
```

Well, the result is that, `data` now are filled with the response coming from `'http://localhost:3001/users/'` route.

Ok so now you could say "Yes but what's the difference between this verbose code and just a direct call to myFunction somewhere in the code?" and the answer is "this is a better approach because the callback is memoized (= will be taken in care by React that caches some operation to increase performances) and will change only if myFunction changes (I mean if you use another function because you have to fetch from another route)".

Comment: ok, but what is the difference if i would use useEffect instead of useCallback in my code above?

Comment: also i don't understand, why to use useCallback if we fetch data inside useEffect? So using useEffect is not enought?

Comment: @Asking If you using a useEffect insted of useCallback you are not memoizing the operation (the result is the same, performances could be different). Of course, as I wrote at the end of the answer, you could call myFuction directly in component's useEffect (but again, result is the same, performances could be different). useCallback is just a different approach to a problem (that, as you know, could be solved in an infinite number of ways).

Comment: For me is not clear why I should use effect  for functions if we don’t pass this function as prop. If I won’t wrap with useeffect the function won’t trigger a rerender, am I right ?  Why do we need a memorised version of the call back besides the situations when we pass function as prop?

Comment: @Asking Yes, if you don't call `execute` in `useEffect` the function won’t trigger a rerender, you are right (`data` will be always `null`). Is not important if you pass function as prop or not. Is the way you are calling that function: you want to call function outside a memoized callback? It's ok but you are not using memoizing optimization provided by React.

Answer (score 0):

`useCallback` is used to prevent *useless* re-rendering of components or its child. If you know about `React.memo()`, `useCallback` is its functional equivalent.

Consider this:

```
const Foo = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Clicked');
  }
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>;
}
```

This will re-render the `Foo` component again and again even when it's not necessary.

Now consider this:

```
const Foo = () => {
  const memoizedHandleClick = 
      useCallback(
          () => console.log('Click happened') 
      ,[]); // Tells React to memoize regardless of arguments.
  return <Button onClick={memoizedHandleClick}>Click Me</Button>;
}
```

In this code, React will memoize the callback function and the callback will not be created multiple times hence no more *useless re-renders*

Comment: Here's a video explanation if you still have some doubt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AyFP5s69N4&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified

Comment: Are you really sure that your initial example will cause a re-render? I made a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-goldstine-06js9?file=/src/App.js) and seems that at `onClick` component is not re-rendered!

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Yes you are right, it won't re-render because no state change is happening whatsoever. I was just giving a simple example to show how to use ```useCallback```